# Вернуть значение в функцию AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, kotlin

Вернуть значение "value" из doInBackround. Перебрал множество решений, в том числе и ответы stackoverflow, не подходят. Возвращается значение нулевое, пустота (если перемещать по переменным, методам). После получения конкретного значения из JSON, если выходит за рамки "Success" переменные исчезают. Как мне передать в "return"? Помогите кодом. Где "return 10" - это должно вернуться моё "value".

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class ParseTask: AsyncTask<Int, Int, Int>(){
    var GLOBAL_VAR:Int? = 0
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Int?): Int? {
        var bebe:Int = 0
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=59.9085638,30.3952677&DC&destinations=59.906638,30.3984863&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyCJYCg5StSenKMjLgEn3zAbAAwpuBESKQc".httpGet().responseString { request, response, result ->
            //do something with response
            when (result) {
                is Result.Failure -> {
                    val error = result.getAs<String>()
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, error)
                }
                is Result.Success -> {
                    var data = result.getAs<String>()
                    val resultJson = JSONObject(data)

                    val rows = resultJson.getJSONArray("rows")
                    val obj = rows.getJSONObject(0)
                    val elements = obj.getJSONArray("elements")
                    val element = elements.getJSONObject(0)
                    val distance = element.getJSONObject("distance")
                    val value = distance.getInt("value")

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "" + value)
                    GLOBAL_VAR = value
                }
            }
        }
        return 10
    }
```

Comment: Даже если сразу делать десериализацию, без обработки, так же не могу достать. И без AsyncTask в новом методе.

Comment: А метод `asyncTask.get()` в вызывающем потоке пробовали?

Comment: Может стоить изучить теорию про области видимости переменных? Многие вопросы отпадут сами собой.

Comment: И еще про асинхронное программирование, AsyncTask в вашем случае абсолютно избыточен.

Comment: Область видимости переменных не применима к "Success".
Error: Modifier 'internal' is not applicable to 'local variable'

Comment: Про AsyncTask конкретнее можно? Если про параметры, то я в курсе что мне необходим только последний, а если нет, то прошу уточнить.

Comment: Если хотите предложить вариант записи переменной в глобальную во время выполнения, то возвращается пустое значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, долго ломал голову...неделю точно. Запрос асинхронный, т.е. ответ придёт не сразу, нужно время. Поэтому я его делаю в AsyncTask. Пытался вызвать значение из запроса в момент создания.!!ОШИБКА ЖЕ!ЗНАЧЕНИЯ ЕЩЕ НЕ ПРИШЛИ!! Перенёс вызов значений на кнопку, как только в логах увижу полученные значения, то жму на кнопку и данные, которые вернул сервер уже подружены! Ура! Тут пример немного другой, т.к. делаю на другом модуле, но суть та же.

> JSON

```
{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Noe"}
```

> MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.sfp.json

import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.httpGet

internal var GLOBAL_VAR:String? = ""
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val startAsync = ParseTask()
         startAsync.execute(GLOBAL_VAR)

    }

    fun jdun(view: View){
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"$GLOBAL_VAR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        Log.d(">>>>>>>>","$GLOBAL_VAR")
    }

   class ParseTask : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String? {
            "https://api.myjson.com/bins/19u5lp".httpGet().responseObject(User.Deserializer()) { req, res, result ->
                val (user, err) = result
                GLOBAL_VAR = user!!.firstName

                println(user!!.firstName)
                println(user!!.lastName)
            }

            return GLOBAL_VAR
        }
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sfp.json.MainActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:onClick="jdun"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> User.kt

```
package com.example.sfp.json

import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.ResponseDeserializable
import com.google.gson.Gson

data class User(val firstName: String = "", val lastName: String = "") {
    class Deserializer : ResponseDeserializable<User> {
        override fun deserialize(content: String) = Gson().fromJson(content, User::class.java)!!

    }
}
```